# Can USB 3.0 tracks be closer together than 5W if they're quite short?

Tags: pcb, usb, differential, layout, crosstalk

I am currently laying out a space constrained PCB which contains some USB 3.0 Superspeed differential pairs. These USB signals are confined to the PCB, going from a Cypress CX3 chip to a USB 3.0 Hub chip. They do not go to or come from a connector. The signals are approximately 30mm long from start to end.

[image: USB 3.0 differential pairs]

According to the advice, the Superspeed pairs should be separated from each other by at least 5x the differential pair spacing. (This is known as the [5W rule](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sllu149e/sllu149e.pdf))

Since the signals are fairly short, and do not go through a connector or cable, would it be possible to push them a little closer than 5W? Say, 4W or 3W?

Comment: How many layers do you have? if > 2, what's your stackup?

Comment: also, I honestly think you're really overdoing it on the length matching - if you don't do these extra meanders, yes, your traces will be mismatched in length by easily up to 2mm. I very much doubt you're controlling the the properties of your PCB and vias well enough to justify taking that much precaution about length matching, and surprise, the main E-field doesn't actually happen between the differential pair, but between each trace and ground (compare: distance and area – the average voltage difference between the differential pair isn't even 2× as high as from single trace to groundplane)

Comment: but by doing the meandering, you reduce distance, especially close to the chip on the right, to traces where you want to go away from as straight as possible.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - It's a 6-layer board. SGP - PGS.  0.11mm between outer layers. 0.99mm between the inner two power layers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - It's hard to know about the length matching. On one hand, almost all of the datasheets and app notes stress the length matching very strongly. On the other hand, a lot of old, [experienced PCB design engineers](https://youtu.be/QG0Apol-oj0?t=2415) laugh at those app notes, and say it's not true.

Comment: 6 layers: great! So, since I see your upper differential pair crosses to a different layer, anyway, what about doing that layer crossing earlier and then route it on the other side of a (good) ground plane beneath the other pair? a plane horizontally between pairs should allow for pretty good attenuation (if it's grounded well enough). Also, in all honesty, your traces aren't *that* long, so cross-talk might not be all that critical.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Neither of the highlighted pairs change layers. On the left they connect to a BGA. On the right, to a QFN.  Also, the other layers are full too. The power layer has a few signals on it, and the far side has diff pairs too.

Comment: Why there is no DC-blocking caps on the second (upper highlighted) trace? Is it USB2 trace? And I agree with Marcus about the serpentine...

Comment: @Ale..chenski - Argh! Well spotted. How did I miss that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document you linked says this: -

[image]

Does that help you? Can you place ground between or can you route on different layers separated by a ground plane? See also section 7.2 of that document.

Comment: Doh! didn't see that next paragraph. Something wrong with my eyes. Sadly I have diff pairs on both sides already. Also, won't adding ground in between them alter the impedance?

Comment: Yes, it'll alter impedance and you'd have to compensate by changing the track widths.

Comment: Coplanar Ground will reduce impedance and allow you to make the differential pair narrower to hit the target impedance - saving even more space.

Comment: I'll allow myself the remark that I do think the advice to put ground-fill in between is to be taken with a fair amount of skepticism. The 5W rule is to limit cross-talk. Violating that, you can get away if you add a very good ground plane in between these two, in hopes the E-fields will happen mostly between tracks and between tracks and the coplanar ground plane. However, especially in a crowded situation, you're very limited in how perfect a ground plane on the same layer can be – <5W isn't really that much space that you can have arbitrarily many vias! I'll venture a guess that this advice

Comment: is hand-me-down advice from a more civil age of lower frequency signals, and not the result of extensive simulation/modelling. (but: I have no simulation of my own, so I'll go away if someone actually says "I do have experience and this isn't right")